# How do I run a DropWizard / Jersey server locally without having to restart & repack to get asset file updates?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey, dropwizard

I'm working on the client side of a project that is using DropWizard. Unfortunately what I'm experiencing is that for me to make a change to assets I have to stop the server, package the assets with maven, and then rerun the server or the assets will not be updated.

I tried adding [dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle) but I'm still seeing the same behavior. Here's the service after adding it:

**Service.java**

```
public void initialize(strap<ServiceConfiguration> strap) {

    // Assets
    strap.addBundle(new ConfiguredAssetsBundle(
            "/dashboard/app/", "/dashboard/", "index.html"
    ));

    // Redirect /dashboard to /dashboard/
    strap.addBundle(new RedirectBundle(ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
            .put("/dashboard", "/dashboard/").build()));
}
```

I'm currently running `mvn package && java -jar target/pack.jar server config.yml`. I tried using Eclipse but I was having to restart it manually and it wasn't repackaging for me so it was slowing things down even further.

This whole process is *reaaaally* slowing me down and I'm hoping it's just my ignorance to the world that is Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assets are packaged under `src/main/resources` then they should just update automatically with Eclipse without a restart being required, so long as you're running the executable service `main()` from within the IDE.

You may need to check that your Maven plugin is set to "generate-resources" on changes but that is just the default setting so should be in place already.

What you're describing is definitely possible in Eclipse - I have personal experience of making resource changes (e.g. change and save an HTML asset) and then seeing an immediate update upon doing nothing more than a browser refresh.

Answer (score 4):

In my Intellij Idea, i am using `JRebel` plug-in for this purpose. JRebel also supports Eclipse.